# Drilldown after clicking on a cell on table visual Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a report on Pentaho that I need to replicate on Power BI. There is a feature on Pentaho to be able to drill down after clicking on a cell value.

Is this possible to achieve on Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Power BI allows you to drill-down on the data in the visual itself, or drillthrough and navigate to another page/bookmark/visual.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-drill

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-drillthrough